# Can you turn a CSS background-image into a submit button using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="search.php">
<input type="text" id="inputSearch"/>
</form>
```

And some CSS:

```
#inputSearch {
    padding:18px 15px 18px 52px;
    font-size:1rem;
    color:#1f5350;
    border:none;
/*defining background image as a search symbol*/
    background: #7accc8 url(search.png) 8px 14px no-repeat;
    background-size:25px 26px;
}
```

The search icon is just a static image. Using JavaScript, how can I grab the CSS background-image and use it to create a clickable submit button without adding further HTML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your search icon in `<a></a>` tags, that way your image will be clickable and can take the user to the page you want once he clicks on it: Here's an example:

```
    <div class="maindiv">
    <form id="myform" name="myform" method="post" action="schitems.php">  
    <input type="search"  id="itemcd" name="itemcd" class="inputfields" placeholder="Type an Ingredient..." />
<a href="search_results.html"><img src="search_icon.jpg" alt="search"></a>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're trying to achieve can't actually be accomplished with raw CSS; you need to use JavaScript and attach a click event handler to the element.

**Unfortunately**, considering you're making use of `background-image`, your image is essentially 'part of' the whole `<input>` element itself, and as far as I'm aware, you can't separate out the click functionality (without making use of a separate element for the image).

Having said that, you can make it so that the form submits when any part of the `<input>` is clicked on with the following. This can be improved by double-checking that there is actually **content** entered into the input before allowing the form submission to fire:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('myform');
var input = document.getElementById('itemcd');
input.onclick = function() {
  if (this.value.length > 0) {
    form.submit();
  }
}
```

```css
#myform {
  width: 260px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

input[type="search"] {
  padding: 18px 15px 18px 52px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #1f5350;
  /*removing boder from search box*/
  border: none;
  /*defining background image as a search symbol*/
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-size*/
  -webkit-background-size: 25px 26px;
  -moz-background-size: 25px 26px;
  -o-background-size: 25px 26px;
  background-size: 25px 26px;
  /*positioning background image*/
  background-position: 8px 14px;
  /*changing background color form white*/
  background-color: #7accc8;
  outline: 0;
}


/*now using placeholder property to change color of placholder text and making it consitent accross the browser by use of prefix*/

input[type="search"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #b1e0de;
}

input[type="search"]:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #b1e0de;
}

input[type="search"]::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #b1e0de;
}

input[type="search"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* interner explorer*/
  color: #b1e0de;
}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">
  <form id="myform" name="myform" method="post" action="schitems.php">
    <input type="search" id="itemcd" name="itemcd" class="inputfields" placeholder="Type an Ingredient..." />
  </form>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)